# Predicted Values in machine learning

Tags: neural-network, random-forest, gbm

I remember reading an article comparing predicted probabilities of boosted, stacked encoders, random forests, and neural network algorithms. One important point I got from the article was that gbm pushes predicted probabilities towards 1 and zero. Does anyone know an algorithm that produces predicted probabilities that are close to 0.5?

Comment: Please just answer what you know or at least suggest an article that could point me in the right direction. I can't even trace the article I read.